# Insert array data into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to insert array into database. Why don't this work?

```
$array_zone = array();
$array_data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($keputusan1)){
$array_zone[] = $row['zone'];
$array_data[] = $row['data'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array_zone);
echo "<br>";
print_r($array_data);
echo "</pre>";

$list_zone = implode(",", $array_zone);
$list_data = implode(",", $array_data);

for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `db`.`table1` (`id`, `domain`) VALUES ('$list_zone', '$list_data')");
}
```

Array output before implode:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 270
    [1] => 270
    [2] => 255
    [3] => 255
)

Array
(
    [0] => ok.com.
    [1] => lo.com.
    [2] => i.com.
    [3] => k.com.
)
```

Result I'm getting:
[image: phpmyadmin]

0 key should go with data in 0 key and 1 key should go with data in 1 key and so on... Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be using `$list_zone` and `$list_data` instead of `$array_zone` and `$array_data`

Comment: @niomaster: I update my question. It's still not working.

Comment: @sg552 did you see my answer. Its what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)**. The result returned in `$keputusan1` is a `SELECT` query. And it certainly returns `zone` and `data` columns.  Say the query is `SELECT zone, data, columns ... FROM tbl1`.

If you use [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) the new query would be

```
INSERT INTO `db`.`table1` (`id`, `domain`) SELECT zone, data FROM tbl1";
```

This will `SELECT` first then `INSERT` it in **one shot**.

The problems with your code are

1. 4 SQL statements. It should be 1.
2. You should use `$array_zone` and `$array_data` instead of `$list_zone` and `$list_data` if for loop is used. But it should not be as of step 1.

Comment: Yes. This solve it and much efficient. I learned new thing today. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that you just forgot to use the loop-index ($i) within the loop
to access the arrays elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
 $array_zone = array('a','b','c','d');
 $array_data = array('1','2','3','4');

print_r($array_zone);
print_r($array_data);

for($i = 0; $i < count($array_zone); $i++)
{
  echo("INSERT INTO `db`.`table1` (`id`, `domain`) VALUES ('$array_zone[$i]', '$array_data[$i]')\n");
}
?>
```

Now replace that echo with your mysql_query call and remove the '\n' at the end...

Comment: Oh I can only choose 1 correct answer. You answer did solve my problem but other user gave me other approach that is much efficient. Anyway I really appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your list_zone (really array_zone) is enclosed in a single set of single quotes, so you're passing one long string. And you're doing it four times. Pass it one pair of values at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this in that way? Probably a good idea to try the `serialize()` function instead of the implode. http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Maybe an even better idea to use JSON for this task. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php